# Add ToolBar to JDesktop

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have little problem with my own project. I have two classes. One of Them Toolbar.java class another class is NewDesktopVersion.java

NewDesktopVersion.java code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //Main frame initializing
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Frame");
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //Internal frame initializing
    final JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Scene", true, true, false);
    desktop.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    desktop.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setBounds(665, 15, internalWidth, internalHeight);

    internalFrame.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Toolbar.java code is:

```
public class ToolBar {

//Toolbar initializing
final JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("Toolbar");

//Buttons for toolbar
JButton cube;
JButton cone;
JButton cylinder;
JButton sphere;

public ToolBar(){
    super();

    toolBar.setFloatable(false);
    toolBar.setOrientation(1);

}

JToolBar getToolBar(){

    return toolBar;

}
```

When I add `desktop.add(new ToolBar())` NewDesktopVersion.java class have problem with this. How I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions

1. Don't give your JDesktopPane a BorderLayout. It must use its own layout to function properly.
2. Put the JDesktopPane into the BorderLayout.CENTER another JPanel that uses a BorderLayout.
3. Put the JToolBar into this same JPanel's BorderLayout.PAGE_START position
4. Or add the setJToolBar to the JFrame in its BorderLayout.PAGE_START position

Comment: Can you tell me properly what I must be do ?

Comment: @ElmarYolçuyev: I just did. If this doesn't help, then improve the question -- post a valid [mcve], explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: When I add ToolBar class to the NewDesktopVersion class it's not compile and output problem

Comment: @ElmarYolçuyev: then 1) read and try to fully understand the error message as usually it's quite clear, and 2) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49970508/edit) your question and show what you're trying to do, the error message, and so forth. Your question remains quite vague, and your code snippets don't show the full picture.